# Using ISNULL function is throwing an error

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access

Table Fields are, `RollNo` DataType is **Number** and `Class` DataType is **ShortText**.

This the query,

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(MAX(RollNo), -1) AS Roll 
FROM 
    Students 
WHERE
    Class = "One"
```

When I run this query, I get an error:

> Invalid operation or syntax using multi-valued field

I want to get a value of `-1` if the column is null, otherwise the maximum value of the `RollNo` with the where condition of `Class` being `One`.

Comment: Are you able to share the table structure

Comment: I have shown the table structure in the post now.

Answer (score 3):

`isnull()` returns a boolean value.  It is really never used, because `is null` is the standard and also supported by MS Access.

I *think* you want `nz()` -- to replace the null value with -1:

```
select nz(max(rollno), -1)
```

If you want to return `NULL` if the value is -1, then use `iif()`:

```
select iif(max(rollno) = -1, null, max(rollno))
```